VirtualBox Guest additions features don't work
VirtualBox guest additions are installed with the required kernel and stuff but still, its features don't work.
Host OS - Windows 11,
Guest - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS,
VirtualBox Version - 7.1.0
Features that don't work:-

Drag n Drop
Shared Folder
Seamless mode
3d acceleration


Good question to ask the VirtualBox guys.

Maybe, "the" answer:
VBox-Menu: Devices > Upgrade Guest Additions... and then
Boot your virtual machine (if you have several, one at a time) and select:
VBox-Menu: Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD Image...
and then run *GuestAdditions.sh (? can't check for correctness right now)
on the CD - if it doesn't start automatically.

Having the exact issue when setting up VM on my new laptop with the same Host and Guest OS and tried every possible fix online.
the correct GA version is installed but even copy paste doesn't work and it's enabled.
Meanwhile Full screen and some minimal other features are working perfectly.
My old laptop host was win10 with every single GA feature working which made me think the problem root might come from the win11 OS?
Or probably refresh rate in Guest OS might not be the same as the Host(144hz) which blocks the seamless mode from working?
I have this in my logfile.
VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x0 -> 0x0) seamless: no, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: no
